# Restore boot-loader after resize dev/sda1 using gparted

Tags: boot-repair

I've been searching on google and stackoverflow for a solution without result.

**Explanation:**

I had to install Windows alongside Ubuntu 16.04. 
I freed up some space from my `dev/sda1` (my Ubuntu was installed on this) using `gparted` from live usb.
It took too much time; around 40min plus. I intentially canceled operation and then restarted my laptop at this time the actual Ubuntu was not loading in boot options of laptop.
I then again run live usb ubuntu and tried to repair boot using Boot-Repair tool but I got this message:

```
Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux (sda1). Then try again.
```

The unknown Linux (sda1)  is my Ubuntu.

I am not able to access it how can i enable grub*** on it?

please help me

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZVDjbcghY6/

Answer (score 0):

If a resize or move operation is cancelled then the file system can be left in an inconsistent or broken state.  This can result in data loss and the inability to restore the ability to boot from a broken file system.

I recommend restoring from backup, or if you do not have a backup then try to recover the file system / important data before proceeding any further.